# lighttpd configuration for virtual host and fastcgi

Tags: configuration, lighttpd

I am trying to set-up a virtual host configuration so that

- requests that go to /cgi-bin/iipsrv.fci are processed by fastcgi
- all other requests are processed by a proxy configuration

So far tough, I have no clue how to achieve this -- i.e. how to write a rule that matches my virtual host, but not the /cgi/bin/* route.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$HTTP[url] = "^/cgi-bin/iipsrv.fci" {
    fastcgi.server = ( "/cgi-bin" =>
                       ( "localhost" =>
                          (
                            "socket"   => "/tmp/php" + PID + ".socket",
                            "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi"
                          )
                       )
                     )

    }
$HTTP[url] != "^/cgi-bin/iipsrv.fci" {
    proxy.server = ( "..." =>
                     ( "localhost" =>
                       (
                         "host" => "192.168.0.101",
                         "port" => 80
                        )
                      )
                    )
    }
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working - when I enable this kind of configuration, nothing is accessible anymore.

Comment: What does it say? Did you take a look at error log?

Comment: $HTTP[url] gives an error Failed to start lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon.

Comment: $HTTP["url"] maybe